# How to calc worst case complixity?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How can I calc. the worst case complexity for these code using big O notation.

```
  int a=0, b=0;

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    a=a+1;
  }

  for(j=0;j<M;j++){
    b=b+j;
  }
```

Comment: By applying what you know about algorithms. Do that and perhaps return with a *specific* problem, not "this is my code and do this and that for me." It's impossible to answer your question anyway because we don't know the input size. What complexity are you talking about at all? Time or space complexity?

Comment: I mean time and space complexity.

Comment: I think regarding to time , it will be O (M + N) bu what about space how can I calc. it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is linear.  The worst case is either N or M, which ever is bigger.  The first loop will run N times, the second loop will run M times.

Comment: thanks a lot , what about the worst case of space of memory

Comment: I guess it would be what takes up the most space in memory, but I am not sure.